# Correct way of adding Page Method to ASP MVC project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pagemethods, webmethod

I'm just getting started with ASP.NET and the MVC model. I've worked my around the basic concepts and have a few models, controllers, and views working fine. I know how to add Web Methods and Page Methods to a Web Service, but cannot figure it out for MVC projects.

I (think) I need to add a Page Method to my project as the correct way of responding to AJAX requests. This is what my controller looks like:

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public class OrderController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Place (ProductSku sku)
        {           
            var order = Order.NewOrder(sku);
            var db = new SystemDiscsLib.Database();
            db.SaveOrder(order);

            return View(order);
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static string GetDate ()
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
```

POSTing to `/Order/Place` works fine, and the view is created displaying the contents of `Views/Order/Place.aspx` and everyone is happy. However, any requests made to `/Order/GetDate` fail with a `The resource cannot be found` error. I (think) I have correctly enabled Page Methods by adding this to my `Web.config`, under `system.web`:

```
    <httpModules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </httpModules>
```

I do not have a view called `GetDate` as I don't want a view, I'll just be returning JSON data. I intend to use JQuery, so I didn't do the `EnablePageMethods` and `ScripManager` stuff, [per this article](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PageMethods are for WebForms, not MVC. Change your method to look more like this:

```
public JsonResult GetDate()
{
  return Json(DateTime.Now.ToString());
}
```

Note that the method is no longer static, and you should not use the `[WebMethod]` attribute.

Comment: +1 This is correct, I had thought the OP wanted to use this method in their view, and missed the request to use jquery.

Comment: That's ridiculously easy and would have been obvious if only I hadn't already read up on PageMethods which sent me barking up the wrong tree. Thank you.

Comment: I believe it is in System.Web.Mvc as well?